# Django визуализация данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Стоит задача в визуализации данных при помощи графов на сайте, есть ли для Django соответствующая библиотека?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеется ввиду визуализация с использованием Django Templates?
Можете воспользоваться [Plotly Dash](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) или [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/), но мой опыт часто выводит к использованию внешнего BI инструмента подключенного к вашей БД или React/Vue фронт взаимодействующий с Django посредством RestAPI

Comment: Вопрос не просто визуализации (графики), а именно графов. Насколько я посмотрел этого функционала в вышеуказанных библиотеках нет

Comment: @Дмитрий Спасибо за уточнение. Тогда нужно смотреть в сторону Tree Charts. Нашел парочку платных решений [AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/hierarchy/tree/) и [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/tree-module). 


Есть OpenSource решения: 
[TreanJS](https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/)
[GraphDracula](https://www.graphdracula.net/) - похоже, что закроет задачу.


Также есть хорошая [ветка обсуждения задачи](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript)